# Cannot read property 'value' of undefined (JS & Typo3)

Tags: javascript

On my website i am using a products search. [see here](http://dyomics.ctw-jena.de/en/products/product-search.html) If you type for example "630" in the search you get some results. Now only the first item can be added to the basket. If you click on another item it comes an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined"

But there is no difference between the first and any other item.

```
<input size="3" maxlength="4" type="text" class="products-input-quantity" id="tt-products-search-id-2" name="ttp_basket[325][quantity]" value="">

<input type="submit" class="btn button-violet" name="order" value="Add to Cart" onclick="if(!document.forms['ShopSearchForm']['ttp_basket[325][quantity]'].value!=''){document.forms['ShopSearchForm']['ttp_basket[325][quantity]'].value=1;};">
```

the value is defined ... but he cant find it or is empty?! If i type manually a number in Qty any item can be added to the basket...but the error is still in the console

Well, this is a little specific but this is still a JavaScript problem :/

Comment: If you run `document.forms['ShopSearchForm']` in your console, you get an empty form. There is nothing by the name "ttp_basket[325][quantity]", in it.

Comment: yes the form is closing in the same line...this is on all sites

Comment: Try asking on the [TYPO3 Forum](http://forum.typo3.org/) (http://forum.typo3.org/) for better and faster help